# Jenkins Slave issue (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.remoting.Launcher)

Tags: maven, jenkins

In Jenkins slave we have change Open JDK from  jdk1.8.0_151 . now when we are running job from Jenkins . getting below error msg .
My Jenkins slave and master are on different Java version .

```
/usr/java/latest/bin/java -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dmaven.artifact.threads=20 -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn -cp /home/bdauser/maven33-agent.jar:/usr/share/apache-maven-3.3.9/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/usr/share/apache-maven-3.3.9/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main /usr/share/apache-maven-3.3.9 /home/bdauser/slave.jar /home/bdauser/maven33-interceptor.jar /home/bdauser/maven3-interceptor-commons.jar 42477
10:49:02 Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
10:49:02 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
10:49:02 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.remoting.Launcher
10:49:02    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
10:49:02    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
10:49:02    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
10:49:02    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
10:49:02    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.main(Maven33Main.java:133)
10:49:02    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.main(Maven33Main.java:64)
10:49:03 ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
10:49:03 java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
10:49:03    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:408)
10:49:03    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:353)
10:49:03    at hudson.slaves.Channels.forProcess(Channels.java:115)
10:49:03    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:294)
10:49:03    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:236)
10:49:03    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:803)
10:49:03    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
10:49:03    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1727)
10:49:03    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:542)
10:49:03    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
10:49:03    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
10:49:03 [BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
10:49:03 [BFA] No failure causes found
10:49:03 [BFA] Done. 0s
10:49:06 Finished: FAILURE`enter code here`
```

Comment: possibly a duplicate. please check this. if so, mark this question as duplicate.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556404/jenkins-build-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-hudson-remoting-launcher

Comment: Now i dont found the tools.jar file with java-1.8.0-openjdk . as it was there in old JDK .I have verified as i have installed the JDK only not JRE .   Please suggest