# I met two unsolvable problems about jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

Firstly this are my configures
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Z0X.png)

It seems that I can't upload the picture, so I copied the error message

my jdk version is jdk1.8.0_152

my maven version is apache-maven-3.6.1-bin

I can run this program in IDEA

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String filePath = "./cifile";
        File dir = new File(filePath);
        // 一、检查放置文件的文件夹路径是否存在，不存在则创建
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();// mkdirs创建多级目录
        }
        File checkFile = new File(filePath + "/filename.txt");
        FileWriter writer = null;
        try {
            // 二、检查目标文件是否存在，不存在则创建
            if (!checkFile.exists()) {
                checkFile.createNewFile();// 创建目标文件
            }
            // 三、向目标文件中写入内容
            // FileWriter(File file, boolean append)，append为true时为追加模式，false或缺省则为覆盖模式
            writer = new FileWriter(checkFile, true);
            writer.append("my content");
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (null != writer)
                writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This program is just a simple write file

So there is no configuration in my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>citest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

</project>
```

The following is my error message

```
Started by user ameng
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\阿蒙\.jenkins\workspace\test
Updating http://114.67.219.61:8080/svn/TeamDesigner at revision '2022-10-21T14:20:55.278 +0800' --quiet
Using sole credentials pengweihao/****** in realm ‘<http://114.67.219.61:8080> VisualSVN Server’
At revision 3

No changes for http://114.67.219.61:8080/svn/TeamDesigner since the previous build
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 64312
[TeamDesigner] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152/bin/java" -cp C:\Users\阿蒙\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-agent-1.14.jar;D:\apache-maven-3.6.1-bin\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;D:\apache-maven-3.6.1-bin/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main D:\apache-maven-3.6.1-bin C:\Users\??\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-4.13.2.jar C:\Users\阿蒙\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-interceptor-1.14.jar C:\Users\阿蒙\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.14.jar 64312
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.remoting.Launcher
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.main(Maven35Main.java:136)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.main(Maven35Main.java:66)
ERROR: ================================================================================
ERROR: Invalid project setup: Connection reset
ERROR: [JENKINS-18403][JENKINS-28294] JDK 'jdk' not supported to run Maven projects.
ERROR: Maven projects have to be launched with a Java version greater or equal to the minimum version required by the controller.
ERROR: Use the Maven JDK Toolchains (plugin) to build your maven project with an older JDK.
ERROR: Retrying with agent Java and setting compile/test properties to point to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152.
ERROR: ================================================================================
Established TCP socket on 64314
[TeamDesigner] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152/bin/java" -cp C:\Users\阿蒙\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-agent-1.14.jar;D:\apache-maven-3.6.1-bin\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;D:\apache-maven-3.6.1-bin/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main D:\apache-maven-3.6.1-bin C:\Users\??\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-4.13.2.jar C:\Users\阿蒙\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-interceptor-1.14.jar C:\Users\阿蒙\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.14.jar 64314
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.remoting.Launcher
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.main(Maven35Main.java:136)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.main(Maven35Main.java:66)
[TeamDesigner] $ cmd.exe /C "D:\apache-maven-3.6.1-bin\bin\mvn.cmd clean package && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------< org.example:citest >-------------------------
[INFO] Building citest 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ citest ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\阿蒙\.jenkins\workspace\test\TeamDesigner\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ citest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (GBK actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ citest ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding GBK, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\阿蒙\.jenkins\workspace\test\TeamDesigner\target\classes
[WARNING] /C:/Users/阿蒙/.jenkins/workspace/test/TeamDesigner/src/main/java/org/example/Main.java:[15,13] 编码GBK的不可映射字符
[WARNING] /C:/Users/阿蒙/.jenkins/workspace/test/TeamDesigner/src/main/java/org/example/Main.java:[22,18] 编码GBK的不可映射字符
[WARNING] /C:/Users/阿蒙/.jenkins/workspace/test/TeamDesigner/src/main/java/org/example/Main.java:[26,18] 编码GBK的不可映射字符
[WARNING] /C:/Users/阿蒙/.jenkins/workspace/test/TeamDesigner/src/main/java/org/example/Main.java:[26,34] 编码GBK的不可映射字符
[WARNING] /C:/Users/阿蒙/.jenkins/workspace/test/TeamDesigner/src/main/java/org/example/Main.java:[27,93] 编码GBK的不可映射字符
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ citest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (GBK actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\阿蒙\.jenkins\workspace\test\TeamDesigner\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ citest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ citest ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ citest ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\阿蒙\.jenkins\workspace\test\TeamDesigner\target\citest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.156 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-10-21T14:20:59+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:457)
    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:404)
    at hudson.slaves.Channels.forProcess(Channels.java:119)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:296)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:236)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:802)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:524)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1897)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I can't understand why my jdk can't support running maven

Secondly, it is clear that the compilation has been successful and the jar package has also been generated, but why does the final result still fail

By the way, I pull files from TortoiseSVN

Related links do not solve my problem because I only have one machine working, no msater and slave

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins Build error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.remoting.Launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556404/jenkins-build-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-hudson-remoting-launcher)

Comment: It seems that I can't upload the picture, so I copied the error message   -  Good, text is better than a screenshot!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to reply to comments. What I want to say is that 'Jenkins Build error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.remoting.Launcher' didn't solve my problem

Comment: I guess you need to add a few dependencies/configurations to your pom.xml. However, I can't tell which ones

Comment: For my program, I don't use any dependencies. If I need to add dependencies or configurations, I have no idea